# Did Hope know her blood would heal Jossie Saltzman

Tags: plot-explanation, legacies

In the latest *Legacies* episode (S01E16), Hope went to Triad Organisation's place (in GA) to save Landon. After she reached there, Landon told her about Malivore and its/his history, might have mentioned in his story how Malivore was formed/created with Wolf-Vamp-Witch blood.

I suppose after knowing this *(Wolf-Vamp-Witch blood thing)*, she figured out that she is the key for Malivore's end.

But my question is,

How did she know *(not guess)*, that her blood would heal Jossie's wound? It was not her guess for sure because she said to Alaric, *"I'll explain it later"*. There was no way she could have known that Malivore was a creation of tri-breed type blood.

Also, if she knew already, why didn't she give her blood to Jossie herself when they were in the cell, captured by Triad people at school.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing the major point. Hope was also shot with the Malivore mud bullet, as she had the mark on her cloth but she was not affected by it and she noticed it while stopping blood fountain while next to Alaric. And she was not affected by the Malivore memory wipe after Landon's mother jump.

So she figures out that it do not affected her, so she suggested her blood for a cure.

Comment: That still won't answer why she said "I will explain later". her this statement suggests that she was sure that it would work. Didn't she think about the slug that **affected her**, which came out of the Malivore? How could she be so sure?

Comment: @RC0993 that slug was a creature, not Malivore itself. Malivore is weak towards Hope, not every creature Malivore ever meet in his whole life.